# Setting the minimum point of a quadratic function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima, quadratic-forms

I want to set the point $(150, 400)$ as the minimum of the quadratic function:

$$f(x,y)= ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 +dx + ey + g$$

To do this, I solve this set of equations:

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2ax + by + d = 0 $$
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = bx + 2cy + e = 0 $$
$$ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = 2a > 0 $$
$$ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} = 2c > 0 $$
$$ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y} = b > 0 $$

by setting $a = c = 1$ and $b = 3$ to meet the above conditions. I can then solve for $d$, $e$, and $g$ by evaluating these equations at the set minimum $(150, 400)$. These values are $-1500$, $-850$, and $-202500$, respectively. However, when I make a contour plot this function, the minimum is nowhere close to the set point (where the black point shows the global minimum of the plot):

[image]

Have I done something incorrectly? I can't figure out why I am not seeing a valley at $(150, 400)$.

Comment: you only need a single unknown to achieve this. Why do you have so many???? Decide on the form of the function you want first

Comment: You need $b^2 - 4ac < 0$ but you picked $(1,3,1)$ for $(a,b,c)$

Comment: As suggested above, you could just assume $b=g=0$ and $a=c=1$ and then solve two equations for $d$ and $e$. This works regardless of where you want the stationary point. The only reason to have more parameters is if you require your quadratic to satisfy some other properties. Anyway, for your case you should have got $e=-1250$

Comment: quick: pick  $a,c > 0$  and $b^2 - 4ac < 0 ,$   then let your polynomial come from expanding out $a(x-150)^2 + b (x-150)(y-400) + c (y-400)^2 $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for this polynomial $$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-300x-800y+182500$$

To get this do nothing, just expand $$(x-150)^2+(y-400)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

The second equation becomes

$$3*150 + 2*400 + e = 0 $$
$$450 + 800 + e = 0$$
$$e = -1250$$

I think you overlooked the $2$ multiplying $c$.

Comment: Don't forget to recompute g after this change!